# Retrieve ID created by Firebase Post

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, post

I am using Firebase API for Unity and I am pushing some data to the realtime database using the Post request
Right after using that Post request I need the created ID for the new node to do something else but I am not sure how to retrieve that ID.

```
Firebase.Instance.Post(uri, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "name", name } },
     delegate { Debug.Log("Name has been added successfully!");  //here is where i need the new ID to do something else },
     delegate { Debug.Log("Something Wrong! .. Please try again later"); });
```

The post function:

```
public void Post<T, K>(URI uri, T body, System.Action<K> onSuccess, System.Action<string> onFail)
        {
            RequestHelper currentRequest = new RequestHelper
            {
                Uri = uri.Path,
                BodyString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body),

                IgnoreHttpException = true
            };
            Debug.Log("BODY_post: " + currentRequest.BodyString);
            RestClient.Post(currentRequest, (exception, res) => ResolveResponse(exception, res, onSuccess, onFail));
        }

void ResolveResponse<T>(RequestException exception, ResponseHelper res, System.Action<T> onSuccess, System.Action<string> onFail)
        {
            string returnedText = res.Text;
            AuthError authError = null;

            try
            {
                authError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthError>(returnedText);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (authError != null && authError.error != null && authError.error.message != null)
                {
                    onFail(BeautifyMessage(authError.error.message));
                }
                else if (exception != null && (exception.IsHttpError || exception.IsNetworkError))
                {
                    onFail(BeautifyMessage(exception.Message));
                }
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                {
                    onSuccess((T)(object)returnedText);
                }
                else
                {
                    onSuccess(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(returnedText));
                }
            }
        }
```

And it calls to the rest api's library post function.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `Firebase.Instance.Post` API. Can you share a link to the library you re using to access Firebase?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-patch its in the firebase rest api

Comment: @mushter that doesn't explain how that `Post` is implemented in your project ..

Comment: @derHugo i added other code snippets, hope this makes it clearer

Comment: In the REST API [calling `POST`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-post) returns the key in the response. From that link: "A successful request is indicated by a 200 OK HTTP status code. The response contains the child name of the new data specified in the POST request."

Comment: The new code snippet help, but we still don't see how the code translates the `res` from the REST API into a result for the `Firebase.Instance.Post` in your first snippet. The code that connects the two will have to pass the key from the response back to the `Firebase.Instance.Post` call.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if i understand correctly, I need to pass the res.text in the ResolveResponse function i just provided, correct?

Comment: Sort of yeah. The exact format of the response is shown in the link, so you'll need to parse/deserialize that and turn it into the response/callback value you want to get in the first snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping the Firebase REST API, where [calling `POST`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-post) returns the key in the response:

> A successful request is indicated by a 200 OK HTTP status code. The response contains the child name of the new data specified in the POST request.
>
> `{ "name": "-INOQPH-aV_psbk3ZXEX" }`

So your response handler will need to parse that result, and return the `"-IN...."` key back to the caller.

Comment: This is what I needed! thank you very much